# Serverless: Handle API key decryption in a lambda function

Tags: python-3.x, aws-lambda, serverless, amazon-kms

I am implementing an API that uses a third party library.

The third party library provides a key which needs to be passed in as an input. The key is dynamic and can change based on consumer/business scenario. The lambda function should be able to decrypt the key.

Can someone suggest a way to decrypt a key? I am exploring aws-kms approach on the side.

Please note: i have noted down the .env way of achieving it. But, today my API is being consumed by one consumer hence one API key. Tomorrow, the number will increase (would result into multiple keys) and i may not be in place to store/update the function.

**Edit:** I need to pass some sensitive information through payload. This can be an alphanumeric value. e.g. 
{"sender": "+123", "secret": "encrypted_value"}
The client and server should share a key using which client can encrypt the info and server (lambda function) should decrypt it.

Any suggestion would be great! Thanks!

Comment: What do you mean decrypt a key? Is it encrypted? If so, how?

Comment: Yes, it would be encrypted. Perhaps, using some aws-kms mechanism. I am not very well versed with aws-kms world. But, I have distinct key which would be passed in encrypted format to API. I would do some more research on this part before i commit. But until then, i wanted to see if there a standard pattern.

Comment: @HeretoLearn. there's not a standard pattern for reference, because we don't know how or when the key is encrypted, or by whom, or with what algorithm.  It is also not clear why the caller would be responsible for passing the key to your API, instead of your API selecting the correct key for the purpose based on the caller's credentials.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot Sorry to open ended question. This is not a key to authenticate the API itself. The third party API i am going to use provides a distinct key based on account used. I need a way to pass this key in payload. Sending the key insecurely will be vulnerable. Perhaps, i can have a secret at global level to encrypt the key from client side and use the same secret to decrypt it on lambda side.

Comment: I'm still unclear why you'd provide the key to the client in any form, when you could authenticate the client based on your API's (separate) authentication mechanism, and based on that, select and use the correct key.

Comment: @michael-sqlbot Consider a scenario in which you can send notification from phone number A or phone number B based on the value of input field API_access_key. The client is an intermediate service which is built in-house. From the sample payloads, access_key makes the difference:
 {"message": "Hello", "access_key": "ask101"} vs {"message": "Hello", "access_key": "ask102"}. It is not my own API key. It is input to be used to make third party API call.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way of doing something like you described on your "edit" section using KMS is:

1. Client calls KMS directly to [generate a data key](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_GenerateDataKey.html). Client will get back a key in its encrypted and plain format.
2. Client encrypts the data with the plain key, throws it away and send encrypted data and encrypted key to the server.
3. Server calls KMS [`decrypt` operation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/APIReference/API_Decrypt.html), gets back the plain key and uses it to decrypt the data. Server throws away the decrypted key and uses the decrypted data as it wishes.

Please let me know if you meant something different, but this is a fairly standard way to use KMS. Of course, you need to lock down all of the APIs using IAM and KMS policies as your use cases determine.

Comment: Thanks @Viccari! I understand that third point in the answer is what i should do on the Lambda function. Thank you for pointers to relevant articles in the AWS documentation. :)

Comment: Yep, that part happens on the Lambda. 1) and 2) should happen on your client.